# Conditional redirect in .htaccess using RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building a directory of my company's projects that will live both locally (using MAMP for the time being) and on our staging server.

What I am trying to do is have a single `.htaccess` that will conditionally redirect depending on where it's being requested.

I have the first part working fine - from the root of the staging server to our home page.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} staging.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.homepage.com [R=301,L]
```

This is the part I cannot fathom. If viewing our local server at the root (e.g. `http://102.168.0.27:8888`) I would like to redirect to a folder on the same domain (e.g. `http://102.168.0.27:8888/directory`). Viewing any folder (`http://102.168.0.27:8888/*`) should not redirect, only when no folder is specified.

Too add to the complexity, that IP address could change and I don't want to have to update it. I also don't want to have to specify folders on that domain that shouldn't redirect; it should be ANY folder.

A different redirect locally is easy enough, I just cannot get it to meet my requirements for folders:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !staging.com
RewriteRule (.*) /directory [R=301,L]
```

To summarise:

- On the staging server root, redirect to home page
- Locally, redirect to a folder if none is specified
- Locally, do not redirect if a folder is specified
- Do not specify the local domain/IP
- Do not specify folder names

Comment: All local envs use the 8888 port? cause you can hook your conditions to that

Comment: Yes, always that port. I'll have a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 8888 port condition for local environment, try this:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8888
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /directory [R=301,L]`

Other files/directories on the local server shouldn't be affected by this rule.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It doesn't redirect at all, even on the root.

Comment: I've updated the answer and moved the condition to be on REQUEST_URI